# <unresolved overloaded function type> when calling a function from a template base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Here is MCVE of my problem:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

template<std::size_t CAPACITY>
class Buffer
{
public:
    template<std::size_t PARAM_SIZE>
    void pushArray(const uint8_t values[PARAM_SIZE])
    {
        // method's body (not important)
    }
};

template<std::size_t CAPACITY>
class BetterBuffer : public Buffer<CAPACITY>
{
public:
    template<typename TYPE>
    void push(TYPE value)
    {
        typedef uint8_t arrayType_t[sizeof(TYPE)];
        const arrayType_t &array = (arrayType_t&)value;
        Buffer<CAPACITY>::pushArray<sizeof(TYPE)>(array);
    }
};

int main()
{
    BetterBuffer<10> buffer;
    buffer.push(100);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler prints the following error message.

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void BetterBuffer<CAPACITY>::push(TYPE) [with TYPE = int; long unsigned int CAPACITY = 10]’:
main.cpp:31:24:   required from here
main.cpp:24:40: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘long unsigned int’ to binary ‘operator<’
             Buffer<CAPACITY>::pushArray<sizeof(TYPE)>(array);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

I compile it with command `g++ -Wall -std=c++17 main.cpp`.

I'm using g++ in version: 'g++ (Ubuntu 7.1.0-5ubuntu2~16.04) 7.1.0'.

If I remove the template parameter from class `Buffer` or move the method `push` from `BetterBuffer` to `Buffer` then program can compile with no problem.

What is wrong with this specific code?

Comment: You can use `Buffer<CAPACITY>:: template pushArray<sizeof(TYPE)>(array);` or `this->template pushArray<sizeof(TYPE)>(array);`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords.

Comment: Thanks! I write in C++ quite a long time but I don't think that I saw this use of keyword `template` before.

Comment: It's time to refresh your knowledge of C++ :) :)